# Java 8 - Improve Sort time for Large number of files by their size

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I looked up [sorting files in directory by size using java array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120151/sorting-files-in-directory-by-size-using-java-array-list) && [How to sort an ArrayList by its elements size in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280257/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-by-its-elements-size-in-java)

My question is what is the best way for the Comparator to be implemented so that sort will be faster? I was told that **the sort for 100k files should be done in seconds not in minutes**, as the file sizes are in long.
Is there a better way to implement the Comparator?

My Comparator is:

```
public static List<File> sortFilesBySize(List<File> xmlFileList) {
     xmlFileList.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::length).reversed());
     return xmlFileList;
}
```

where

```
private static List<File> xmlFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
```

xmlFileList is populated as:

```
pathList = pathList.subList(0,filterCount);
for (Path filePath : pathList)
    xmlFileList.add(filePath.toFile());
```

filterCount is how I filter by number of files to be sorted

and the sortFilesBySize is invoked as:

```
long startSortMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
sortFilesBySize(xmlFileList);
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startSortMillis;
```

By varying the number of files sorted as 5k, 10k 20k etc. I get

1. 5k ----> 1329 ms
2. 10k ---> 2808 ms
3. 20k ---> 29790 ms
4. 40k ---> 428408 ms
5. 80k ---> 838658 ms
6. 100k --> 1159034 ms

It can be observed that after 20k the sort takes minutes. Any suggestions how I can lower the sort time?

I also looked up https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html to see if I could improve my current implementation, but nothing seemed to jump out.

Comment: I believe your question belongs [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Have you tried caching the file size?

Comment: Have you considered that `File.length()` might be a relatively slow operation? Perhaps caching that would help, i.e. wrap `File` with a custom class containing `File` and the size, implement `Comparable`, then sort that.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Efficiency of the way comparator works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878398/efficiency-of-the-way-comparator-works)

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed caused by the system calls on `File.length()`. The number of them increases more than linearly with the number of files. Do cache it as suggested. You will find that the sort time almost vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

Try caching the length:

```
public static List<FileWithCachedLength> sortFilesBySize(List<FileWithCachedLength> xmlFileList) {
    xmlFileList.sort(Comparator.comparing(FileWithCachedLength::length).reversed());
    return xmlFileList;
}
```

Where:

```
public class FileWithCachedLength {
    private final File file;
    private final int length;
    // getters omitted
    public FileWithCachedLength( File f ) {
        file = f;
        length = f.length();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, this is due to the cost of the `File.length()` method.

If you had a method like this:

```
public static <T, R> Function<T, R> memoized(Function<? super T, ? extends R> f) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(f);
    Map<T, R> map = new HashMap<>();
    return t -> map.computeIfAbsent(t, f);
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
public static List<File> sortFilesBySize(List<File> xmlFileList) {
    xmlFileList.sort(Comparator.comparing(memoized(File::length)).reversed());
    return xmlFileList;
}
```

Which would only incur the cost of calling `File.length()` once for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the answers and they were very helpful. I chose the implementation suggested by MiguelKVidal.

I started by reviewing Java Pairs - from http://www.baeldung.com/java-pairs.

After the implementation, my sort time was nice and low. But it is still longer to walk the directory path:

1. 5k ----> Sort (16 ms) -----> WalkDirectoryPath(102 seconds)
2. 10k --->Sort(31 ms)------->WalkDirectoryPath(94 seconds)
3. 20k---->Sort(68 ms)------->WalkDirectoryPath(177 seconds)
4. 40k---->Sort(131 ms)----->WalkDirectoryPath(328 seconds)
5. 80k---->Sort(158 ms)----->WalkDirectoryPath(1219 seconds)
6. 100k--->Sort(322 ms)---->WalkDirectoryPath(479 seconds)